# sharepoint alerts for grand totals

Tags: alert, custom-alert-templates

Is it possible to setup alerts in sharepoints to email the numeric value of a grand total which changes each day

see screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

OOTB this is not possible. I would recommend creating a site workflow which for example runs once a day. If Nintex is available, it is very easy.

Comment: I see so the first 3 options offered by Turun wont work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the alerts for every update on the  listitem

**Option 1 : Event Receiver**

You can write a event receiver  and calculate the sum and and send email 
 **Reference Link :**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242790/cannot-send-mail-in-sharepoint-using-event-receiver

**Option 2: SharePoint Designer Workflow**

You can create a SharePoint designer workflow and calculate the sum and send email.

If you was the alerts on regular interval of time(daily, hourly, etc...)

**Option 3: Custom Timer job**

You can create a custom timer job for the calculation and  calculate the sum and send email.

[Send Email using Custom Timer Job in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1ce8ad/create-custom-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013-for-send-email/)

Comment: which option is the easiest to try?

Comment: That  was based on your Requirement